# onBillingSetupFinished never called

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing

I have always worked with Java but this time I am trying to develop in Kotlin, I have an app that will have a button to pay to remove the ads (with Google Play's billing system) but I can't get it to work.

- I have already uploaded my signed apk to Play Console and create the product that has the ID remove_ads
- This is what I have in the AndroidManifest.xml file `"android.permission.INTERNET"` and `"com.android.vending.BILLING"`
- In build.gradle:
  `implementation("com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0") implementation("com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:4.0.0")`
- In my Kotlin Class "Settings":

OnCreate:

```
btnRemoveAds.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@Settings, "Click Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build()

        billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                Toast.makeText(this@Settings, "SetupFinished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                if (billingResult.responseCode ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@Settings, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                    billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(
                        SkuType.INAPP
                    ) { billingResult, list ->
                        if (list.size != 0){
                            if (list.get(0).purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED){
                                setPlus(true)
                                setResult(RESULT_OK)
                            } else{
                                queryAvaliableProducts()
                            }
                        } else{
                            queryAvaliableProducts()
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(this@Settings, "NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Toast.makeText(this@Settings, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            }
        })
    }
```

The only Toast I can see when pressing the button is "Click Button"

These are my methods:

```
private fun queryAvaliableProducts() {
    val skuList: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    skuList.add("remove_ads")
    val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(INAPP)
    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(
        params.build()
    ) { billingResult, skuDetailsList -> // Process the result.
        if (skuDetailsList!!.size != 0) {
            val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList[0])
                .build()
            val responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(
                this@Settings,
                billingFlowParams
            ).responseCode
        }
    }
}

private val purchasesUpdatedListener =
    PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
        // To be implemented in a later section.
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
            && purchases != null
        ) {
            for (purchase in purchases) {
                handlePurchase(purchase)
            }
        } else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
            // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
        } else {
            // Handle any other error codes.
        }
    }

fun handlePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
    if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
            val acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                .build()
            billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(
                acknowledgePurchaseParams,
                acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener
            )
        }
    }
}

var acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener =
    AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener { billingResult ->
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            setPlus(true)
            setResult(RESULT_OK)
            finish()
        }
    }
```

I also implemented a button to check connection status after billingClient.startConnection

```
btnConnectionState.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@Settings, billingClient.connectionState.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

I am getting 2 (Connected) as a result so it seems weird to me that onBillingSetupFinished and onBillingServiceDisconnected never get executed, are there any errors in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no errors in your code afaik except the Toast itself. `onBillingServiceDisconnected` isn't called on the main thread. If you put a try catch around it like so:

```
try {
    Toast.makeText(this@Settings, "NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    Log.e("MyApp", "Error", ex)
}
```

It will print an error like this

> 06-05 00:00:38.713  8595  9215 E MyApp   :
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't toast on a thread that has not
> called Looper.prepare()

You can also print the thread the callback is called from:

```
Log.e("MyApp", "Running on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
```

and it will tell you

> Running on PlayBillingLibrary-1

So switch back to the main thread for the Toast (there are ways) or use a simple Log statement to verify that the method is called.

Comment: I have deleted the Toast and now I get this message: _Item you requested is not available for purchase_, It's weird because its status in the Play Console is "Active" I am going to publish my application (in production) hoping that will solve the problem, thank you very much

Comment: @JP711 np, feel free to mark my answer as correct ;-)